# pandas mapping one key to multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I have a dataframe that look like this

`df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '02', 3], [2, '01', 5], [3, '03', 8], [4, '04', 1]], columns=['Student', 'activityCode', 'pts'])`

```
    Student activityCode    pts
0   1   02  3
1   2   01  5
2   3   03  8
3   4   04  1
```

I want to map the activityCode to an activityName and create a table with pts aggregated at student and activityCode level. But the tricky thing is 02 corresponds to `swimming and football`. The mapping table:

| activityCode | activityName |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Swimming |
| 02 | Swimming and football |
| 03 | Running |
| 04 | Football |

and I want the output to be

```
    Student activityName    pts
0   1   Swimming    3
1   1   Football    3
2   2   Swimming    5
3   3   Running     8
4   4   Football    1
```

I tried

`df['activityCode'].map({'01': 'Swimming', '02':['Swimming', 'Football'], '03':'Running', '04':'Football'})` but obviously, instead of two rows I got one row with ['Swimming', 'Football'] in the activityName column.

```
0    [Swimming, Football]
1                Swimming
2                 Running
3                Football
```

How should I write the code to map the `activityCode` so that it creates two rows with different `activityName` but same in all other columns for 02? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is it only activity `02` that needs to be split or are the others? Can we split on `and` or is there `'swimming and diving'` which should not be split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to explode the `activityName` column.

```py
df['activityName'] = df['activityCode'].map({'01': 'Swimming', '02':['Swimming', 'Football'], '03':'Running', '04':'Football'})
df.explode('activityName')
```

This will return a DataFrame where, for any cells in `activityName` that were a list, there will be as many rows as there are elements in that list, one for each element, with the values in the other rows the same as their values in the original row. For any rows where the `activityName` value was not a list, they will exist in the new DataFrame as-is.